# Python extent of optimisation (Common subexpression elimination)

Tags: python, optimization, python-2.7

Say I have to split a line into a key and a value, and put it in a `dict` called `props`. Let the separator be `=`. I can do it this way:

```
props[line.partition('=')[0]] = line.partition('=')[2]
```

or this:

```
splits = line.partition('=')
props[splits[0]] = splits[2]
```

Will the first form partition the string twice or will it get optimised to do it only once? I guess it is implementation dependent, but do the common implementations do this (CPython Jython, IronPython)? I know it is premature optimisation. I am new to python, and I am just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is split twice in the first case.

Python cannot be certain, as a dynamic language, that the `line` value is immutable and that the `.partition()` method will return the same results every time. It has no choice but to execute `line.partition('=')` each time.

Comment: I would certainly *hope* you could assign to `splits` once it's yours.  Or do you have to slice it and create a whole new object before you can do useful stuff?  (Either way, the second example probably won't do what the OP is hoping...it won't affect the original string.)

Comment: @cHao: Ah, I see what you mean now.

Comment: Actually, i think you were right in the first place.  `partition` returns a tuple, and tuples appear to be immutable; you'd have to have the values in a list before you could reassign them.

Comment: @cHao: Adjusted once more.

Comment: Thanks folks! Actually I never wanted to reassign `splits[0]`. It was a typo in the code, I updated the question now. Good additional knowledge for me, though :)

Comment: Okidoki, removed the part about the assignments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Python bytecode compiler/interpreter is very straightforward (dare I say, primitive) and performs no optimizations except some very basic constant folding and throwing out asserts if asked. Certainly no common sub-expression elimination pass for you.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for mentioning sub-expression elimination. I can read up more  on that now. Didn't know that's what it is called. I'll update the question with that, so that it will be useful for future searchers.